# How to work with simple xml framework for maps

Tags: android, xml

I need to put some data in xml from editText. Lets say like below:

```
<properties>
  <property key="one">first value</property>
  <property key="two">second value</property>
</properties>
```

So, each time i will give a new entry it will append another element inside properties root in my xml file. Lets say i took key= x & text against x = "Something"

so, the xml will become:

```
<properties>
  <property key="one">first value</property>
  <property key="two">second value</property>
  <property key="x">Something</property>
</properties>
```

moreover, i want to search for a specific value. Lets say i am using a editText & typed a key x and in button click i can retrieve the value against the key=x; which is "Something".

How to do this using simple xml framework?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement and XML parser.  There are many tutorials out there on how to do this.  Search on Google  for "sax parser tutorial" and look at them. I'd link one, but SO doesn't really like links that might be dead later